# Xperia Z1 camera parameters iso-values

Tags: android, camera, sony

I want to create a Sony Camera Add-on.

I cannot get any "iso-values" related camera parameters from my Xperia Z1 device. The Sony Camera app (SomcCameraWidget.apk) does have ISO settings though.

Can it be that the iso values aren't exposed to the standard Android Camera API? Is there a proprietary call that I can make, or Sony library that I can include? Or maybe the iso values are only controllable after setting other parameters first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the iso values are only accessible via private APIs.  However, if there is enough community demand for opening up these APIs then it may be possible to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Really awesome that Sony engineers are on StackOverflow answering questions! :)

Can the ISO values not be programmed to work with the standard camera parameters? Then it wouldn't be necessary to expose private APIs, and all the licenses and infrastructure that is needed...

Comment: Yes, that could certainly be done and would be the preferred way to go.  Don't want to deviate from vanilla Android if we don't have to.  The biggest overhead is just making the change at the platform level to expose the ISO values to the standard camera APIs.

Comment: I'm willing to make any sacrifices. Let me know if you need my help.